# Slurm error: "slurmstepd: error: no task list created!"

Tags: hpc, slurm, supercomputers

I'm attempting to run a simple job on Slurm but am getting a cryptic error message:

> slurmstepd: error: no task list created!

I've run thousands of other jobs identical to the job I'm running here (with different parameters), but only this one run has yielded this error. Does anyone know what might cause this error? Any help would be appreciated!

Here's my full job file:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name=candidates
#SBATCH --output=logs/candidates.%A.%a.log
#SBATCH --error=logs/candidates-error.%A.%a.log
#SBATCH --array=1-10000
#SBATCH --requeue
#SBATCH --partition=scavenge
#SBATCH --time=1-00:00:00
#SBATCH --mem=40g
#SBATCH --mail-type=FAIL
#SBATCH --mail-user=douglas.duhaime@gmail.com
bin/candidates numbers numbers numbers
```